# How to run two applications from two XCode debugger instances on the iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator

I would like to run two applications from two XCode GUI instances on iPhone Simulator,

The two apps communicate with each other using socket and I would like to do step by step debugging in each app to debug the some logic internally.

I wish to use the debugger and do step by step in each XCode instance while the two apps are running on the iPhone simulator
The issue is that I can only use breakpoint\stop the run in one XCode instance while the other XCode\app seems to be running (the title in the target is "Running ..") but could not catch the breakpoint or even see any print\traces in the XCode debug console.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Thank you!
Ronen

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have two iPhone simulators at the same time. The only way to go would be to launch one app on simulator and one on device.

Comment: I don't want to have two iPhoneSimulator, I wish to run both apps on same IphoneSimulator, It is working but I can't debug each app, stop on breakpoint in both apps

Comment: Well, I don't think it is possible either...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried debugging two apps simultaneously on the iOS simulator, and simple things seem to work correctly.

Remember that on iOS, apps that are not in the foreground are generally suspended unless they register background tasks.  So only the foreground one is going to make any progress.  But that's true regardless of whether you are in the debugger or not.

If one or the other apps has registered a background task, and that background task isn't getting any time when you have this scenario of two apps running under the debugger, please file a bug with an example of your scenario at http://bugreporter.apple.com.

But if you want to follow foreground processing in the two apps, you'll have to manually foreground the one you want to run as you are stepping along.  But that's just a reflection of how apps run on iOS.